# Why is the underneath border shifting right underneath the text?

Tags: css, hover

If you look at the following site: staging.cancerwellness.com, and high light the top menu, you will see that the item turns red, but the underline is shifting right.

Here is the css code:

```
    #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary>li.mega-menu-item.mega-toggle-on>a.mega-menu-link {
     position:relative;
     text-decoration:none; 
      display:block;     
   }

   #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary>li.mega-menu-item.mega-toggle-on>a.mega-menu-link:after {  
     display:block;    
     content: '';
     border-bottom: solid 1px #cf2734;
     border-bottom-width: medium;  
     transform: scaleX(0);  
     transition: transform 250ms;
     transform-origin:100% 50%  
   }

    #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary>li.mega-menu-item.mega-toggle-on>a.mega-menu-link:hover:after { 
     transform: scaleX(1); 
     transform-origin:   100% 50%;         
     display:block; 
    }
```

FWIW, I did try display:inline-box but it didn't work.

What could be causing the border shifting right?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: You need a position: absolute on the "#mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary>li.mega-menu-item>a.mega-menu-link:after" selector

The reason why this is happening is because the element that is created by the :after selector takes up space, which will cause the link to shift over to make room. The position: absolute essentially makes the :after element float above the link instead of sitting next to it.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.